# Email current page button does not work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have this little piece of code in a site to send the current page by email. It works on Firefox but not in Chrome. I've googled the issue but haven't found any answer. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

```
<script>
    function emailCurrentPage(){
        // In comments, other things I've tried
       //window.location.href="mailto:?subject="+document.title+"&body="+escape(window.location.href);
       //document.location.href="mailto:?subject="+document.title+"&body="+escape(document.location.href);

        document.location="mailto:?subject="+document.title+"&body="+escape(document.location);
}
</script>
<button onclick="emailCurrentPage();">
    Send by email
</button>
```

Thank you.

Comment: The button appears to work fine for me in the latest version of Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/Lp52W/

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Oddly enough, your fiddle works in my version of Chrome too... So maybe the problem it's not the actual code, but something else. I just don't get why it still works in FF.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function:

```
window.location.href="mailto:?subject="+document.title+"&body="+encodeURI(document.location);
```